# Show hide div by jquery depending on 2 values from 2 selectbox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

anybody can help me?
I want to make show hide some div by jquery depending on values from two selectbox
this my code

```
$("#offer_seeking_select").change(function(){
var offer_seeking=$(this).val();
var selectedCategory=$("select.category-select:visible").last().find("option:selected").val();

$.get(www_base+"adding.php?cID="+selectedCategory+"&offer="+offer_seeking,function(data){
if(data.status=="ok"){$("#forms").html(data.html).trigger("forms_content_updated")
}})});
```

html code

```
<select id="drop-2"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select>
<select id="drop-3"><option value="offer">Offer</option><option value="seeking">Seeking</option></select>
<div id="forms"></div>
```

and some 'div' in adding.php will be show hide in #forms depending on values when select from #drop-2 and drop-3, example if I select 1 from drop-2 and offer from drop-3 show #one and #three hide #two, else select 2 from drop-2 and seeking from drop-3 show #two and #three hide #one

this html in file adding.php because I can't get cID and offer in file adding.php

```
<div id="one">abc</div>
<div id="two">123</div>
<div id="three">789</div>
```

Comment: You could take some time to clean up your code and do less string concatination.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this which uses classes that correspond to the id of the select, you may need to refactor to fit your required logic as I a not sure I fully understood.

```
$('#foo, #bar').change(function(e) {
    var $elm = $(e.target);
    var $elmDiv = $('.' + $elm.attr('id'));

    if ($elm.val() !== "") {
        $elmDiv.show();
    } else {
        $elmDiv.hide();
    }
});​
```

here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8C8GG/1/)

Comment: class 'category-select' in two selectbox #drop-2 and #drop-3

Comment: in my case, at first must select category value from selectbox #drop-2 and then select category value from selectbox #drop-3, after this must pass variables selectedCategory and offer_seeking to adding.php file, this file work with Mysql and give result to $.get(www_base+"adding.php?cID="+selectedCategory+"&offer="+offer_seeking,function(data){
if(data.status=="ok"){$("#forms").html(data.html).trigger("forms_content_updated")
}})}); and embed data (div#1 or div#2) from this result to div#forms

Comment: this is adding.php file if(isset($_GET['cID'])){ 
$catID = $_GET['cID'];
$query = "select * from category where sub=0 and catID=".$catID ;
$ketqua = mysql_query($query);
$raw    = mysql_fetch_array($ketqua);
 if($raw['OldNew']==2){
 echo "<div id='1' class='fblock cloud clr error'>
    somthing content
  </div>";
 }
 else if($raw['OldNew']==1){echo "<div id='2' class='fblock cloud clr error'>content2
  </div>";}
 else {echo "<div id='2' class='fblock cloud clr error'>content2
  </div>"}
}

Comment: When I check in fact variables 'selectedCategory and offer_seeking' don't pass to php file and or php file don't get variables from the script

Comment: that sounds like a seperate question